# LaTeX3 Error in MOdiagram package

Tags: bugs, modiagram

I try to compile empty document with `MOdiagram` package (38448 (0.2g)) and get an LaTeX3 error

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Variant form 'cNc' deprecated for base form
(LaTeX3)        '\dim_compare:nNnTF'. One should not change an argument from 
(LaTeX3)        type 'n' to type 'c': use a 'v' variant?
```

TL2018 (updated). Possible package or LaTeX3 bug.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{modiagram}

\begin{document}

% Nothing

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've logged a request to update the code: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/modiagram/pull-requests/3

Comment: @JosephWright There are still errors `! LaTeX3 Error: Variant form 'nNN' deprecated for base form '\__MOdiagram_split_energy:NNN`

Comment: I've hopefully sorted that too!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it describes has been fixed in an up to date distribution.