# Molecular orbital diagram for CH2

Tags: tikz-pgf, modiagram

I'm trying to draw an MO diagram for CH2 by mimicking this MO diagram (excluding the orbital images), but things don't look like the way I want it to be. I really want to make it nice and similar to the image, but what I'm doing right now just seems sad and would really appreciate it if someone can help me.

[image]

I tried using MOdiagram package, but needs A LOT of work on it, especially with the overall size of the diagram because it is too small when I typeset. So, it would be really nice if someone can help me. Please and thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{modiagram}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\begin{MOdiagram}[labels-fs=\scriptsize]
        \AO(1cm){s}[label={2s}]{0.5;}
        \AO(-0.4cm){p}[label={2p}]{2;}
        \node at (1cm, -1){C};
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \AO(3cm){s}[label={$2\mathrm{a}_1$}]{0;pair}
        \AO(3cm){s}[label={1e}]{0.9;pair} 
        \AO(3cm){s}{1.1;pair} 
        \AO(3cm){s}[label={$3\mathrm{a}_1$}]{2;pair}
        \AO(3cm){s}[label={$4\mathrm{a}_1$}]{3;}
        \AO(3cm){s}[label={2e}]{3.9;}
        \AO(3cm){s}{4.1;}
        \node at (3cm, -1){\ce{CH_2}};
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \AO(5cm){s}[label={1s}]{2.5;}
        \node at (5cm, -1){H};
\end{MOdiagram}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Most likely `\documentcalss{article}` should be `\documentclass{article}`. And if I correct this, I get errors on my machine. Most likely you are not to blame for them but I am wondering which TeX installation you are using.

Comment: @marmot Sorry for that. I tried fixing some details of it. See if the copy and paste works now, when you typeset. Please and thank you.

Comment: Thanks for updating you MWE! Unfortunately I run into the issue https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474476/121799 . (Anybody else having the same problem?)

Comment: Try adding the package \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} It should do the trick. @marmot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used `MOdiagram` before, but as you tagged the question [tikz-pgf](/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), here is a (simple) *pure* Ti*k*Z solution.

I am not even using a chemistry package and writing BeH<sub>2</sub> as `BeH$_2$` 
:) but you really should change that in your document.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dotted] (-3,0)--(-.3,3)--(.3,3)--(4,-1)--(.3,-4.5)--(-.3,-4.5)--cycle;
\draw[dotted] (-3,-1.5)--(-.3,1.5)--(.3,1.5)--(4,-2)--(.3,-6.5)--(-.3,-6.5)--cycle;
\draw[thick] (-.3,3)--(.3,3) (-.3,1.5)--(.3,1.5) (-.8,0)--(-.2,0) (.2,0)--(.8,0) (-.3,-4.5)--(.3,-4.5) (-.3,-6.5)--(.3,-6.5) (-3,0)--(-3.6,0) node[midway,below] {$2p_z$} (-3.8,0)--(-4.4,0) node[midway,below] {$2p_y$} (-4.6,0)--(-5.2,0) node[midway,below] {$2p_x$} (-3,-1.5)--(-3.6,-1.5) node[midway,below] {$2s$} (4,-2)--(4.6,-2) node[midway,below] {$\Phi_\mathrm g$} (4,-1)--(4.6,-1) node[midway,below] {$\Phi_\mathrm u$};
\draw[dotted] (-4.6,0)--(1.9,0);
\draw (0,0) node[below] {$\pi_\mathrm u^\mathrm n$};
\draw (0,.75) node {$\sigma^*_\mathrm g$};
\draw (0,2.25) node {$\sigma^*_\mathrm u$};
\draw (0,-5.5) node {$\sigma_\mathrm u$};
\draw (0,-4.5) node {\rotatebox{90}{$\rightleftharpoons$}};
\draw (0,-6.5) node {\rotatebox{90}{$\rightleftharpoons$}};
\draw (0,-7) node {$\sigma_\mathrm g$};
\draw (-4.2,4) node {Be};
\draw (0,4) node {BeH$_2$};
\draw (4.2,4) node {2 H (\textsc{salc}s)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]