# tikz: molecular orbitals for ICl

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemistry, axis

While modiagram is bugged ([LaTeX3 Error in MOdiagram package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474476/latex3-error-in-modiagram-package)) I decide to make my own molecular orbitals diagram for iodine chloride ICl based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13863/molecular-orbital-diagrams-in-latex). 
Could you suggest how to add the relative vertical energy axis of the various orbitals, and possibly add the eigenvalues as well?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\moup}{\textuparrow}
\newcommand{\modown}{\textdownarrow}
\newcommand{\moupdown}{\textuparrow\textdownarrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\centering
\def\sbaseline{0em};
\def\pbaseline{14em};
\def\ssplit{6em};
\def\psplit{12em};
\def\pextend{5em};
\def\psso{4em};
\def\pxyoffset{1em};
\def\mwidth{3em};
\def\hsep{2em};

\tikzstyle{split} = [densely dashed,draw=gray]
\tikzstyle{orbital} = [rectangle, rounded corners, fill=white, draw=black, minimum width=3.5ex, minimum height=3.5ex]
\tikzstyle{label}   = [rectangle, minimum width=3.5ex, node distance=3.5ex]

%1s splitting
\draw        (\mwidth/-2-\hsep*2,\sbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\sbaseline);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\sbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2        ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/2);
\draw        (\mwidth/-2        ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/2)  -- (\mwidth/2         ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/2);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/2         ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/2)  -- (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\sbaseline);
\draw        (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\sbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/+2+\hsep*2,\sbaseline);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\sbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2        ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/-2);
\draw        (\mwidth/-2        ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/-2) -- (\mwidth/2         ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/-2);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/2         ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/-2) -- (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\sbaseline);

%left 1s
\draw[] (-\mwidth-\hsep,0em) node[orbital] (l1s) {\moupdown};
\node[label, below of=l1s] (l1sl) {$5s$};

%right 1s
\draw[] (\mwidth+\hsep,0em) node[orbital] (r1s) {\moupdown};
\node[label, below of=r1s] (r1sl) {$3s$};

%sigma bonding
\draw[] (0em,\ssplit/-2) node[orbital] (sb) {\moupdown};
\node[label, below of=sb]  (sbl) {$\sigma$};
\node[label, left of=sb, node distance = 9ex] {\tiny{\color{gray}{$\Psi_{a}+\Psi_{b}$}}};

%sigma antibonding
\draw[] (0em,\ssplit/2) node[orbital] (sa) {\moupdown};
\node[label, below of=sa] (sal) {$\sigma^{*}$};
\node[label, left of=sa, node distance = 9ex] {\tiny{\color{gray}{$\Psi_{a}-\Psi_{b}$}}};

%orbital labels
\node[label, below of=l1sl, node distance=6em]   (a)    {\smash[b]{\ce{I}}};
\node[label, right of=a   , node distance=\mwidth+\hsep]   (ab)   {\ce{ICl}};
\node[label, right of=a   , node distance=\mwidth*2+\hsep*2]  (b)    {\ce{Cl}};

%Title
\node[label, below of=ab  , node distance=3em]   (desc) {Cloruro di iodio ICl};

%2p splitting
\draw        (\mwidth/-2-\hsep*2-\pextend,\pbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\pbaseline);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\pbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline+\psplit/2);
\draw        (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline+\psplit/2)  -- (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline+\psplit/2);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline+\psplit/2)  -- (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\pbaseline);
\draw        (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\pbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/+2+\hsep*2+\pextend,\pbaseline);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\pbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline+\psplit/-2);
\draw        (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline+\psplit/-2) -- (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline+\psplit/-2);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline+\psplit/-2) -- (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\pbaseline);

\draw[split] (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\pbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline-\psso+\psplit/2);
\draw        (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline-\psso+\psplit/2)  -- (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline-\psso+\psplit/2);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline-\psso+\psplit/2)  -- (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\pbaseline);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\pbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline+\psso+\psplit/-2);
\draw        (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline+\psso+\psplit/-2) -- (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline+\psso+\psplit/-2);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline+\psso+\psplit/-2) -- (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\pbaseline);

%left 2p
\draw[] (-\mwidth-\hsep,\pbaseline) node[orbital] (l2pa) {\moupdown};
\node[orbital, left of=l2pa] (l2pb) {\moup};
\node[orbital, left of=l2pb] (l2pc) {\moup};

\node[label, below of=l2pb] (l2pl) {$2p$};

%right 2p

\draw[] (\mwidth+\hsep,\pbaseline) node[orbital] (r2pa) {\moupdown};
\node[orbital, right of=r2pa] (r2pb) {\moup};
\node[orbital, right of=r2pb] (r2pc) {\moup};

\node[label, below of=r2pb] (r2pl) {$2p$};

%sigmap bonding
\draw[] (0em,\pbaseline+\psplit/-2) node[orbital] (spb) {\moupdown};
\node[label, below of=spb]  (spbl) {$\sigma$};

%sigmap antibonding
\draw[] (0em,\pbaseline+\psplit/2) node[orbital] (spab) {};
\node[label, below of=spab]  (spabl) {$\sigma^{*}$};

%pi antibonding levels
\draw[] (-\pxyoffset,\pbaseline+\psso-\psplit/2) node[orbital] (ppabx) {\moupdown};
\node[label, below of=ppabx]  (ppabxl) {$\pi_{x}$};
\draw[] (+\pxyoffset,\pbaseline+\psso-\psplit/2) node[orbital] (ppaby) {\moupdown};
\node[label, below of=ppaby]  (ppabyl) {$\pi_{y}$};

%pi antibonding levels
\draw[] (-\pxyoffset,\pbaseline-\psso+\psplit/2) node[orbital] (ppbx) {\moup};
\node[label, below of=ppbx]  (ppbxl) {$\pi^{*}_{x}$};
\draw[] (+\pxyoffset,\pbaseline-\psso+\psplit/2) node[orbital] (ppby) {\moup};
\node[label, below of=ppby]  (ppbyl) {$\pi^{*}_{y}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: At least to me it is completely unclear what you are asking. At the very least, please add the code that you are using, the link is ambiguous.

Comment: Code added. In barely words, I need an axis placed left to the diagram with the energy values (e.g. 0.3819 elettronvolt) of the orbitals

Comment: I'm not a chemist and I don't understand the chemistry jargon. Can you add a freehand drawing of the desired result.

Comment: @AndréC https://imgur.com/r6RHLzf

Comment: Please edit your question with the image.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it is necessary to draw a vertical red line of a height equal to the distance between `Cloruro di iodio` and the **empty** node at the very top. Is that it?

Comment: Yes. MOdiagram can do it, but seems to be bugged since several months

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100484/discussion-between-user3204810-and-andrec).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a figure is built, its bounding box is updated as it is built. This bounding box is a node named `current bounding box`.

So I traced its left side by shifting it to the left at the very end of the code.

```
\draw[red,line width=3pt] ([xshift=-3mm]current bounding box.north west) -- (current bounding box.south west);
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\moup}{\textuparrow}
\newcommand{\modown}{\textdownarrow}
\newcommand{\moupdown}{\textuparrow\textdownarrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\centering
\def\sbaseline{0em};
\def\pbaseline{14em};
\def\ssplit{6em};
\def\psplit{12em};
\def\pextend{5em};
\def\psso{4em};
\def\pxyoffset{1em};
\def\mwidth{3em};
\def\hsep{2em};

\tikzstyle{split} = [densely dashed,draw=gray]
\tikzstyle{orbital} = [rectangle, rounded corners, fill=white, draw=black, minimum width=3.5ex, minimum height=3.5ex]
\tikzstyle{label}   = [rectangle, minimum width=3.5ex, node distance=3.5ex]

%1s splitting
\draw        (\mwidth/-2-\hsep*2,\sbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\sbaseline);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\sbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2        ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/2);
\draw        (\mwidth/-2        ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/2)  -- (\mwidth/2         ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/2);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/2         ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/2)  -- (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\sbaseline);
\draw        (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\sbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/+2+\hsep*2,\sbaseline);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\sbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2        ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/-2);
\draw        (\mwidth/-2        ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/-2) -- (\mwidth/2         ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/-2);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/2         ,\sbaseline+\ssplit/-2) -- (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\sbaseline);

%left 1s
\draw[] (-\mwidth-\hsep,0em) node[orbital] (l1s) {\moupdown};
\node[label, below of=l1s] (l1sl) {$5s$};

%right 1s
\draw[] (\mwidth+\hsep,0em) node[orbital] (r1s) {\moupdown};
\node[label, below of=r1s] (r1sl) {$3s$};

%sigma bonding
\draw[] (0em,\ssplit/-2) node[orbital] (sb) {\moupdown};
\node[label, below of=sb]  (sbl) {$\sigma$};
\node[label, left of=sb, node distance = 9ex] {\tiny{\color{gray}{$\Psi_{a}+\Psi_{b}$}}};

%sigma antibonding
\draw[] (0em,\ssplit/2) node[orbital] (sa) {\moupdown};
\node[label, below of=sa] (sal) {$\sigma^{*}$};
\node[label, left of=sa, node distance = 9ex] {\tiny{\color{gray}{$\Psi_{a}-\Psi_{b}$}}};

%orbital labels
\node[label, below of=l1sl, node distance=6em]   (a)    {\smash[b]{\ce{I}}};
\node[label, right of=a   , node distance=\mwidth+\hsep]   (ab)   {\ce{ICl}};
\node[label, right of=a   , node distance=\mwidth*2+\hsep*2]  (b)    {\ce{Cl}};

%Title
\node[label, below of=ab  , node distance=3em]   (desc) {Cloruro di iodio ICl};

%2p splitting
\draw        (\mwidth/-2-\hsep*2-\pextend,\pbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\pbaseline);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\pbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline+\psplit/2);
\draw        (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline+\psplit/2)  -- (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline+\psplit/2);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline+\psplit/2)  -- (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\pbaseline);
\draw        (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\pbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/+2+\hsep*2+\pextend,\pbaseline);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\pbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline+\psplit/-2);
\draw        (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline+\psplit/-2) -- (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline+\psplit/-2);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline+\psplit/-2) -- (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\pbaseline);

\draw[split] (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\pbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline-\psso+\psplit/2);
\draw        (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline-\psso+\psplit/2)  -- (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline-\psso+\psplit/2);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline-\psso+\psplit/2)  -- (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\pbaseline);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/-2-\hsep  ,\pbaseline)            -- (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline+\psso+\psplit/-2);
\draw        (\mwidth/-2        ,\pbaseline+\psso+\psplit/-2) -- (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline+\psso+\psplit/-2);
\draw[split] (\mwidth/2         ,\pbaseline+\psso+\psplit/-2) -- (\mwidth/2+\hsep   ,\pbaseline);

%left 2p
\draw[] (-\mwidth-\hsep,\pbaseline) node[orbital] (l2pa) {\moupdown};
\node[orbital, left of=l2pa] (l2pb) {\moup};
\node[orbital, left of=l2pb] (l2pc) {\moup};

\node[label, below of=l2pb] (l2pl) {$2p$};

%right 2p

\draw[] (\mwidth+\hsep,\pbaseline) node[orbital] (r2pa) {\moupdown};
\node[orbital, right of=r2pa] (r2pb) {\moup};
\node[orbital, right of=r2pb] (r2pc) {\moup};

\node[label, below of=r2pb] (r2pl) {$2p$};

%sigmap bonding
\draw[] (0em,\pbaseline+\psplit/-2) node[orbital] (spb) {\moupdown};
\node[label, below of=spb]  (spbl) {$\sigma$};

%sigmap antibonding
\draw[] (0em,\pbaseline+\psplit/2) node[orbital] (spab) {};
\node[label, below of=spab]  (spabl) {$\sigma^{*}$};

%pi antibonding levels
\draw[] (-\pxyoffset,\pbaseline+\psso-\psplit/2) node[orbital] (ppabx) {\moupdown};
\node[label, below of=ppabx]  (ppabxl) {$\pi_{x}$};
\draw[] (+\pxyoffset,\pbaseline+\psso-\psplit/2) node[orbital] (ppaby) {\moupdown};
\node[label, below of=ppaby]  (ppabyl) {$\pi_{y}$};

%pi antibonding levels
\draw[] (-\pxyoffset,\pbaseline-\psso+\psplit/2) node[orbital] (ppbx) {\moup};
\node[label, below of=ppbx]  (ppbxl) {$\pi^{*}_{x}$};
\draw[] (+\pxyoffset,\pbaseline-\psso+\psplit/2) node[orbital] (ppby) {\moup};
\node[label, below of=ppby]  (ppbyl) {$\pi^{*}_{y}$};

\draw[red,line width=3pt] ([xshift=-3mm]current bounding box.north west) -- (current bounding box.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Comment: explanation added :-)